# What is the difference between objects VMA (Virtual Memory Area:) and PTE (Page Table Entry)?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, posix

What is the difference between objects VMA (Virtual Memory Area: [`struct vm_area_struct`](http://netlib.narod.ru/library/book0010/part1_43.htm#l15113), with which operates the kernel Linux) and PTE (Page Table Entry, with which operates MMU), and why we require VMA and not enough PTE?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The virtual memory address space of each process is divided into virtual memory areas (VMAs) where all the memory in one VMA is contiguous and shares certain properties such as permissions.  For example, a process might have one VMA for its code, one VMA for each type of data, one VMA for each distinct memory mapping (if any), etc.

Each VMA consists of a number of pages, where a page is the unit for moving between main physical memory and backing store.

Each page has an entry in the Page Table, to indicate whether the page is currently in physical memory (in which case it points to the physical memory address of the page) or currently “paged out” on the system’s backing storage (in which case it points to the backing storage address of the page copy).

So each VMA has multiple PTEs.

The function of the VMA is to define a contiguous area of virtual memory (contiguous virtual addresses, not contiguous physical addresses) with the correct permissions.

The function of the Page Table is to manage paging between main physical memory and backing store, and to be the communication point between the system/hardware (the MMU) and the OS software.

Comment: Thanks! **1.** About: “why we require WMA and not enough PTE?” - I mean that why we require WMA if we can get all of this information (ranges of allocated contiguous physical memory, permissions, etc...) from PT(PTEs), I.e. motivation to use WMA, as I understand we can get this information from single WMA more faster than from many PTEs, isn't it? **2.** And MMU doesn't use WMA, and only linux-kernel uses WMA to find free contiguous physical space, isn't it? **3.** And is there limit of number of PTEs in a single WMA?

Comment: @Alex 1. The memory in a VMA is contiguous virtually, not physically.  So the information in the VMA is not the same as the PT.  I edited the answer to clarify this point and answer the second question in your original post. 2. Correct, MMU doesn't use VMA (it has no way of seeing it), but linux-kernel isn't looking for free contiguous physical space, only virtual space. 3. There is no limit to the number of pages (and hence PTEs) in a VMA other than the limit on the size of virtual memory imposed by the architecture (32-bit, 64-bit, etc.)

Comment: Thanks! I.e. linux-kernel require WMA to find a contiguous area of virtual memory. But my be you can say, what does use linux-kernel to find a contiguous area of **physical** memory?

Comment: It could use the Page Table to find a contiguous area of physical memory, but since page-swapping is happening all the time, a contiguous area will not remain contiguous for very long!

Comment: Yes, but we can make memory pinned, then it will not swap. Or if we allocate contiguous area of physical memory by using `kmalloc()` then is it already pinned?

Comment: @Alex I think you may still have the distinctions between physical and virtual memory slightly confused. kmalloc() allocates kernel virtual memory, not physical memory, although the two concepts are quite tightly coupled.  Typically, the OS software is not concerned with physical memory, only virtual memory.  Some exceptions exist, e.g. in the area of optimizing paging i/o, but for the most part the programmer's view is solely of virtual memory.

Comment: Yes, I know, but can I allocate contiguous area of physical memory by using `kmalloc()` in kernel-space, then remap it to user-space by using `mmap()`, and then make memory pinned by using `mlock()`?

Comment: Interesting question.  I don't know the answer off-hand.